# Solaris 11 express and indirection

Tags: bash, solaris, sh, passwd, indirection

I am trying to use bash indirection in Solaris 11 express to change the password for a user. The code I am using is

```
$ passwd testuser << MARKER
> testpassword
> testpassword
> MARKER
```

When I run this, I still get prompted for a password on the console. The same code works on Ubuntu 10.04.

I tried to run the same thing in bash, sh with same results. Is there something Solaris specific that I need to be doing?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to use [expect](http://expect.sourceforge.net) like [this](http://honglus.blogspot.com/2010/03/change-solaris-user-password-with.html).

Comment: Thanks for the link. Do you know why the behavior for my script is different on Solaris? Does it have to do with the shell I am using?

Comment: I am guessing here, but i think it's reading its input directly from the console in a similar way as ssh does.

Comment: I ended up modifying the shadow file instead to change a users password. But the expect solution seems like a better solution if it is available on the machine.